# Concat multiple row and column in single row mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing data in following format

```
id    |    name   |   age
----------------------------
1     |    John   |   24
2     |    Sam    |   NULL
3     |    Ron    |   32
4     |    Harry  |   44
```

now i want to fetch this into one row like

```
1:John:24,2:Sam,3:Ron:32,4:Harry:44
```

I have tried group_concat but it gives me only one columns values separated by comma, is it possible in mysql ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use group_concat and concat together:

```sql
SELECT group_concat(concat(id, ':', name, ':', IFNULL(age,''))) 
FROM table1
```

You can do this to get the ":" moved over

```sql
SELECT group_concat(concat(id, ':', name, IFNULL(concat(':',age),''))) 
FROM table1
```

And here's an updated [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dd7f/14) that hims056 created.

Comment: But, this drops Sam (null age). Need to take that into account also.

Comment: @prashant - He has already updated. See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dd7f/11)

Comment: @prashant You might need to move the `:` into the IFNULL if you don't need it when age is null.

Comment: @xecaps12 how can I move : into IFNULL can you please elaborate little more

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 select concat(id, ':',name, ':', age) as total_concated 
 from your_table 
 where 1
```